# magento custom url rewrites to .html for cms pages

Tags: url, magento, url-rewriting

I am moving an ecommerce site into magento and would like to preserve as many indexed links as possible. For example: the about page's url is `domain.com/about.html`. Magento writes the url as `domain.com/about`. If I add a custom rewrite and force the .html to be re-written to the end I get a 404 page not found error.

Is what I am trying to do possible? I have also tried re-indexing the store and that did not help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can make a small module, you can use the `cms_controller_router_match_before` event, dispatched in the `Mage_Cms_Controller_Router` class, to handle the `.html` suffix in the URL keys of the CMS pages (by removing it when it is present in the identifier passed in the `condition` object).

Otherwise, you can get almost the same result by adding `.html` at the end of the URL keys.

Comment: I suppose just adding .html to the URL keys will suffice, I really didn't think about it at first. There wouldn't be any reason these pages would get indexed by Google differently would there?

Comment: No, as long as the .html suffix is present in the URL keys, the pages won't be reachable anymore without it in the URL.
But in the code, you will also have to refer to the pages with the suffix, so if you use default Magento CMS pages, there could still be some places where the old key could be used (eg, footer links).

Comment: Works for me, a nice easy solution. Thanks :)

Comment: I find it strange that adding `.html` to categories and products is a simple setting, but CMS pages has nothing remotely close. :/